# How to declare the expression if selector has a comma ","?

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

Given this JSON:

```
{
  "Key with, coma": ["I have a comma", "Does't work"],
  "Key without coma": ["I don't have a coma", "It works"]
}
```

The following throws an error:

```
$['Key with, comma'][*]
```

No problem with this:

```
$['Key without comma'][*]
```

Is there a way to escape the comma?

I'm using https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath inside Lingo4g Indexing project descriptor.

If you check with this tool it seems to work: jsonpath.curiousconcept.com

But if you use this tool it doesn't: http://jsonpath.com/

The expression is being passed to Lingo4g a Java based clustering tool  through a JSON value:

```
"fieldMapping": {
        "Key with, comma": "$['Key with, comma'][*]",
        "Key without comma": "$['Key without comma'][*]"
      }
```

Comment: It works in https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com - what implementation are you using?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the "Java" tag applies here?

Comment: Using: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath